# Trig Algebra Question

Tags: trigonometry

This isn't a homework question it is revision for an exam.

Solve the Equation $\dfrac {4-2\sqrt{2}\sin x}{1+\cos x} = 1$ for the interval $0<x<360,  x\ne 180$

The answer is $70.5$ according to the answer sheet and I've checked it is right with Desmos.

I've tried multiplying by $1+\cos x$ then subtracting the $1$ and converting to $\tan x$ but cannot get the correct answer or work backwards from the answer.

Can someone please show me how to solve this?

Update:
I finally cracked it! Thanks to "Deepak" in the comments for the pointer and someone else on another forum!

[image]

My new question then, is: What should I have noticed that would have made me do it this way first rather than trying to rearrange and divide by $cosx$ to get $tanx$?

Comment: We can't find your error if you don't show your work.  MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$.  Also \sqrt 2 gives $\sqrt 2$ with the bar above the $2$.  If you have more than one character in the square root, put them in braces to get the bar to extend, so \sqrt {121} gives $\sqrt {121}$

Comment: Very good point, I'll upload my workings

Comment: The best approach is to convert to $R\sin(x+\alpha)$.

Comment: Another "best approach" is to substitute $\cos(x)$ by $1-\sqrt{\sin(x)}$ resulting in $(3\sin(x)-2\sqrt2)^2=0$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe How can you substitute $\cos x=1-\sqrt{\sin x}$?

Comment: Not at all: was a typo.  Substitute $\cos(x)$ by $\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put
$$t=\tan(\frac x2)$$
use the identities

$$(1+t^2)\sin(x)=2t\;$$
$$\text{ and }\; (1+t^2)\cos(x)=1-t^2$$

the equation
$$4-2\sqrt{2}\sin(x)=1+\cos(x)$$
becomes

$$4(1+t^2)-4t\sqrt{2}=1+t^2+1-t^2=2$$

or

$$2t^2-2t\sqrt{2}+1=0$$
$$=(\sqrt{2}t-1)^2$$